# Access index of last element in data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I've looking around for this but I can't seem to find it (though it must be extremely trivial).

The problem that I have is that I would like to retrieve the value of a column for the first and last entries of a data frame. But if I do:

```
df.ix[0]['date']
```

I get:

```
datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 10, 16, 0)
```

but if I do:

```
df[-1:]['date']
```

I get:

```
myIndex
13         2011-12-20 16:00:00
Name: mydate
```

with a different format. Ideally, I would like to be able to access the value of the last index of the data frame, but I can't find how.

I even tried to create a column (IndexCopy) with the values of the index and try:

```
df.ix[df.tail(1)['IndexCopy']]['mydate']
```

but this also yields a different format (since df.tail(1)['IndexCopy'] does not output a simple integer).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 179, accepted):

The former answer is now superseded by [`.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iloc.html):

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"date": range(10, 64, 8)})
>>> df.index += 17
>>> df
    date
17    10
18    18
19    26
20    34
21    42
22    50
23    58
>>> df["date"].iloc[0]
10
>>> df["date"].iloc[-1]
58
```

---

The shortest way I can think of uses `.iget()`:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"date": range(10, 64, 8)})
>>> df.index += 17
>>> df
    date
17    10
18    18
19    26
20    34
21    42
22    50
23    58
>>> df['date'].iget(0)
10
>>> df['date'].iget(-1)
58
```

Alternatively:

```
>>> df['date'][df.index[0]]
10
>>> df['date'][df.index[-1]]
58
```

There's also `.first_valid_index()` and `.last_valid_index()`, but depending on whether or not you want to rule out `NaN`s they might not be what you want.

Remember that `df.ix[0]` doesn't give you the first, but the one indexed by 0.  For example, in the above case, `df.ix[0]` would produce

```
>>> df.ix[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-489-494245247e87>", line 1, in <module>
    df.ix[0]
[...]
KeyError: 0
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. 

However, I have another data frame in which df.ix[0] seems to give the first row of the data frame, even though the first index is not 0. In particular, the result of df.index[0] is not 0, and yet df.ix[df.index[0]] and df.ix[0] do give the same result. Why is that?

Comment: I'd need to see the index, but I suspect it's because the index is non-numerical, in which case accessing by integer *can* behave like it's an index, and not a key.  This is because there's no ambiguity in what you're asking for if you ask for `Something(["A", "B", "C"])[1]`, but what do you want if you have `Something([1,2,3,4])[1]`?  Read the various sections [here in the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/gotchas.html#integer-indexing) on some of the headaches involved.

Comment: How to use df['xxx'][df.index[0]] for a float? I have a float 56.7888 and it's converted to 56 instead of 57

Comment: Calling `iget()` gives `'Series' object has no attribute 'iget'`.

Comment: Using pandas for 4 years, this is the first time i've seen iget in any place of stackoverflow,tutorials, codes etc.

Answer (score 29):

Combining @comte's answer and dmdip's answer in [Get index of a row of a pandas dataframe as an integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41217310/get-index-of-a-row-of-a-pandas-dataframe-as-an-integer/42853445#42853445)

```
df.tail(1).index.item()
```

gives you the value of the index.

---

Note that indices are **not** always well defined not matter they are multi-indexed or single indexed. Modifying dataframes using indices might result in unexpected behavior. We will have an example with a multi-indexed case but *note this is also true in a single-indexed case*.

Say we have

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,1,3,3], 'y':[3,3,5,5]}, index=[11,11,12,12]).stack()

11  x    1
    y    3
    x    1
    y    3
12  x    3
    y    5              # the index is (12, 'y')
    x    3
    y    5              # the index is also (12, 'y')

df.tail(1).index.item() # gives (12, 'y')
```

Trying to access the last element with the index `df[12, "y"]` yields

```
(12, y)    5
(12, y)    5
dtype: int64
```

If you attempt to modify the dataframe based on the index `(12, y)`, you will modify two rows rather than one. Thus, even though we learned to access the value of last row's index, **it might not be a good idea if you want to change the values of last row based on its index** as there could be many that share the same index. You should use `df.iloc[-1]` to access last row in this case though.

**Reference**

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.item.html

Answer (score 8):

```
df.tail(1).index
```

seems the most readable

Comment: This does not return a number but: RangeIndex(start=6, stop=7, step=1)

Comment: alex: from the returned `index`, the `start=6` indicates the offset of the last element. So, `df.tail(1)` gets the last element, `df["your_column"][6]` would be the last element, for `your_column`, etc (but `df.last_valid_index()` gives you just the number)

Answer (score 5):

dataframe_object.index returns the list of all the index, to get any range of index you can use the list properties.

**To get the last element index:**

```
dataframe_object.index[-1]
```

**To get the First element index:**

```
dataframe_object.index[0]
```

**To get the index of first x elements index:**

```
dataframe_object.index[0:x]
```

**To get the index of last x elements index:**

```
dataframe_object.index[-3:]
```

**Example**

```
last_record_index = betweenMeals_df.index[-1]
```

Answer (score 4):

It may be too late now,  I use `index` method to retrieve last index of a DataFrame, then use `[-1]` to get the last values:

For example,

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((4, 1)), columns=['A'])
print(f'df:\n{df}\n')

print(f'Index = {df.index}\n')
print(f'Last index = {df.index[-1]}')
```

The output is

```
df:
     A
0  0.0
1  0.0
2  0.0
3  0.0

Index = RangeIndex(start=0, stop=4, step=1)

Last index = 3
```

Answer (score 2):

You want .iloc with double brackets.

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"date": range(10, 64, 8), "not_date": "fools"})
df.index += 17
df.iloc[[0,-1]][['date']]
```

You give .iloc a list of indexes - specifically the first and last, [0, -1]. That returns a dataframe from which you ask for the 'date' column. ['date'] will give you a series (*yuck*), and [['date']] will give you a dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

Pandas supports NumPy syntax which allows:

```
df[len(df) -1:].index[0]
```