# Get index of a row of a pandas dataframe as an integer

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Assume an easy dataframe, for example

```
    A         B
0   1  0.810743
1   2  0.595866
2   3  0.154888
3   4  0.472721
4   5  0.894525
5   6  0.978174
6   7  0.859449
7   8  0.541247
8   9  0.232302
9  10  0.276566
```

How can I retrieve an index value of a row, given a condition?
For example:
`dfb = df[df['A']==5].index.values.astype(int)`
returns `[4]`, but what I would like to get is just `4`. This is causing me troubles later in the code.

Based on some conditions, I want to have a record of the indexes where that condition is fulfilled, and then select rows between.

I tried

```
dfb = df[df['A']==5].index.values.astype(int)
dfbb = df[df['A']==8].index.values.astype(int)
df.loc[dfb:dfbb,'B']
```

for a desired output

```
    A         B
4   5  0.894525
5   6  0.978174
6   7  0.859449
```

but I get `TypeError: '[4]' is an invalid key`

Comment: `df.query` and `pd.eval` seem like good fits for this use case. For information on the `pd.eval()` family of functions, their features and use cases, please visit [Dynamic Expression Evaluation in pandas using pd.eval()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53779986/dynamic-expression-evaluation-in-pandas-using-pd-eval).

Answer (score 108, accepted):

The easier is add `[0]` - select first value of list with one element:

```
dfb = df[df['A']==5].index.values.astype(int)[0]
dfbb = df[df['A']==8].index.values.astype(int)[0]
```

---

```
dfb = int(df[df['A']==5].index[0])
dfbb = int(df[df['A']==8].index[0])
```

But if possible some values not match, error is raised, because first value not exist.

Solution is use `next` with `iter` for get default parameetr if values not matched:

```
dfb = next(iter(df[df['A']==5].index), 'no match')
print (dfb)
4

dfb = next(iter(df[df['A']==50].index), 'no match')
print (dfb)
no match
```

Then it seems need substract `1`:

```
print (df.loc[dfb:dfbb-1,'B'])
4    0.894525
5    0.978174
6    0.859449
Name: B, dtype: float64
```

Another solution with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) or [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
print (df[(df['A'] >= 5) & (df['A'] < 8)])
   A         B
4  5  0.894525
5  6  0.978174
6  7  0.859449

print (df.loc[(df['A'] >= 5) & (df['A'] < 8), 'B'])
4    0.894525
5    0.978174
6    0.859449
Name: B, dtype: float64
```

---

```
print (df.query('A >= 5 and A < 8'))
   A         B
4  5  0.894525
5  6  0.978174
6  7  0.859449
```

Answer (score 59):

To answer the original question on how to get the index as an integer for the desired selection, the following will work :

```
df[df['A']==5].index.item()
```

Answer (score 8):

Little sum up for searching by row:

This can be useful if you don't know the column values ​​or if columns have non-numeric values

if u want get index number as integer u can also do:

```
item = df[4:5].index.item()
print(item)
4
```

it also works in numpy / list:

```
numpy = df[4:7].index.to_numpy()[0]
lista = df[4:7].index.to_list()[0]
```

in [x] u pick number in range [4:7], for example if u want 6:

```
numpy = df[4:7].index.to_numpy()[2]
print(numpy)
6
```

for DataFrame:

```
df[4:7]

    A          B
4   5   0.894525
5   6   0.978174
6   7   0.859449
```

or:

```
df[(df.index>=4) & (df.index<7)]

    A          B
4   5   0.894525
5   6   0.978174
6   7   0.859449
```

Answer (score 5):

The nature of wanting to include the row where `A == 5` and all rows upto but **not** including the row where `A == 8` means we will end up using `iloc` (`loc` includes both ends of slice).

In order to get the index labels we use `idxmax`.  This will return the first position of the maximum value.  I run this on a boolean series where `A == 5` (then when `A == 8`) which returns the index value of when `A == 5` first happens (same thing for `A == 8`).

Then I use `searchsorted` to find the ordinal position of where the index label (that I found above) occurs.  This is what I use in `iloc`.

```
i5, i8 = df.index.searchsorted([df.A.eq(5).idxmax(), df.A.eq(8).idxmax()])
df.iloc[i5:i8]
```

[image]

---

***numpy***

you can further enhance this by using the underlying numpy objects the analogous numpy functions.  I wrapped it up into a handy function.

```
def find_between(df, col, v1, v2):
    vals = df[col].values
    mx1, mx2 = (vals == v1).argmax(), (vals == v2).argmax()
    idx = df.index.values
    i1, i2 = idx.searchsorted([mx1, mx2])
    return df.iloc[i1:i2]

find_between(df, 'A', 5, 8)
```

[image]

---

***timing***
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Or you can add a for loop

```
for i in dfb:
    dfb = i

for j in dfbb:
    dgbb = j
```

This way the element '4' is out of the list