# How to get index of an element in csv whose entry matches with an entry in a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a text file **abc.txt** consisting of ids:

```
301KG0KXAFQBZD5C6JXD5Y3V32D2HR
301KG0KXAFQBZD5C6JXD5Y3V32DH26
302OLP89E2C9N8P0X6CR0PPD2YZCAY
302U8RURK26C60PPXRC1CNX2MCEVN0
304QEQWK0SPEVKOLV9OP6J7HIQ70OT
306996CF7ZPUJFKUNNN3E4QSGJU1BT
306996CF7ZPUJFKUNNN3E4QSGJV1BU
306W7JMRZ13CUF4FM8WITED0UP08BK
307FVKVSZUKO92ENXOUP70BZ9DE74R
3087LXLJ7PLKP7BSW65ZJPY3QPFF0L
3087LXLJ7PLKP7BSW65ZJPY3QPHF0N

and so on
```

All I've to do is:

for each string in **abc.txt**, find and return the index number of **xyz.csv** whose column named **HITID** contains that string and assign it to index variable.

My attempt:

```
clm = pd.read_csv('xyz.csv')

f = open('abc.txt', 'rb')

for entry in f:
    # if clm['HITId'].str.contains(entry).any()

    index =clm[clm['HITId']==entry].index.item()
    print(index)
```

Getting an error that says:

```
  File "approve_reject_hits_fingerD.py", line 89, in <module>
    index =clm[clm['HITId']==entry].index.item()
  File "/Users/AjayB/anaconda3/envs/MyDjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/base.py", line 716, in item
    return self.values.item()
ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar
```

and when I use the line:

```
index =clm[clm['HITId']==entry].index[0]
```

Then I come up with this:

```
  File "approve_reject_hits_fingerD.py", line 89, in <module>
    index =clm[clm['HITId']==entry].index[0]
  File "/Users/AjayB/anaconda3/envs/MyDjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3958, in __getitem__
    return getitem(key)
IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

Newish to python and specifically pandas, so tried these attempts referring:

[Find element's index in pandas Series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18327624/find-elements-index-in-pandas-series)

[Get index of a row of a pandas dataframe as an integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41217310/get-index-of-a-row-of-a-pandas-dataframe-as-an-integer/42853445)

How to tackle this syntactically?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude - it is good, [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and compared values from `f` each `entry`

Comment: csv file has the column 'HITId' with similar ids like those in abc.txt file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is problem no matching any value, so error. Possible solution is use `next` with `iter` for return first matched value if exist else some default value, here `no match`:

```
clm = pd.read_csv('xyz.csv')

f = open('abc.txt', 'rb')

for entry in f:

    index =clm[clm['HITId']==entry].index
    print(index)
    print (next(iter(index), 'no match'))
```