# reduction operation 'argmax' not allowed for this dtype

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, max

**How to Take index of Last Cell in ColumnB?**

I will iterate through all rows, by taking values in there. For that iteration i wanted to *take index value of max row in particular column* with pandas in python. `df['columnNameB'].idxmax()`

I also tried using `axis=1` or `axis='columns` gave other strange errors.

`idxmax()` works in Series of pandas and `df['colNameB']` already gives as a series of columnB values, then why `idxmax()` does not work properly?

code is below;

```
#reading from csv file url-s
def readCSV(path_csv):
    df=pd.read_csv(path_csv)
    return df

fileCSV=readCSV(r'C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\urls.csv')
print(fileCSV['columnURLnames'].idxmax())
"""for i in range(len(fileCSV.columns(1))):
    xUrl=fileCSV.iloc[0,i]
    print(xUrl)
"""
```

edit:

```
   columnA    columnB                   columnC
0   book      www.amazon.com=page?1..   onstock
1   headphone www.amazon.com=page?1..   outstock
2   NaN       www.alibaba.com..         NaN
3   NaN       www.amazon....            NaN
4   lightbulb    NaN                    inStock
```

I need to get number 3. Because index of max value in columnB is 3

**solved**: from [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15862034/access-index-of-last-element-in-data-frame?noredirect=1&lq=1)

```
length_of_column_urls=fileCSV['columnURLnames'].last_valid_index()

for i in range(0, length_of_column_urls+1 ):

    xUrl=fileCSV.iloc[i,1]
    print(xUrl)
```

Comment: WHY is row 3 the the "max" value for column B?  Maximum based on what criteria?

Comment: the last data found cell in column B

Comment: Got an answer from [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15862034/access-index-of-last-element-in-data-frame) post. `fileCSV['columnB'].index[-1]`

Comment: In fairness, that's an answer to a question quite different from the one you asked.

Comment: yeah, that is not be an answer. it gives 4 not three. it counts all columns

Comment: @TimRoberts answer should be last_valid_index() method from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15862034/access-index-of-last-element-in-data-frame?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1):

idxmax returns the index of the highest value. There is no such value for a series of url names (strings).

Edit: I think instead of idxmax you are looking for something like

```
len(fileCSV.index)
```

Comment: Can you expand meaning of `There is no such value for a series of url names (strings)`

Comment: Pandas calls numpy `.argmax` to do this function.  `argmax` only works on numeric values.  Pandas stores strings as objects, which numpy doesn't handle.

Comment: I assume you have a list of urls in your .csv file. Perhaps we can give a better answer if you show us an example of your data and your desired output.

Comment: @bitflip I added visual of csv

Comment: What output do you want to get? The number of rows? (In this case 3)

Comment: @TimRoberts if I could make `int(fileCSV['columnURLnames'])` sth like it, from columnB values?

Comment: @bitflip the index of max value in column B I will use in loop instead of  `len(fileCSV.columns(1))`